# Replace image tag docker-compose with sed command via Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sed, docker-compose

I want to replace the image tag in the docker-compose file with ssh via Jenkinsfile.

Ex:

From this

> image: user/service:v0.1

To This

> image: user/service:v1.0

```
...
steps {
  ...
  sh 'ssh user@hostname sed -E -i.bak "s/(.user\\\\/service:).*/\1v1.0/" docker-compose.yml'
  ...
}
...
```

But, I get an error message like this.

> bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Tried swapping the quotes? `  sh "ssh user@hostname sed -E -i.bak 's/(.user\\\\/service:).*/\1v1.0/' docker-compose.yml"`

Answer (score 2):

Quoting in `ssh` command lines can be complicated because you need to escape things twice for the remote shell and the local shell.

Things can be somewhat alleviated by switching to a different delimiter so you don't have to escape the slash.

```sh
   sh '''ssh user@hostname "sed -E -i.bak 's%(user/service:).*%\1v1.0%' docker-compose.yml"'''
```

(I also removed the dot before `user/service`; if it plays a crucial role which isn't revealed in this example, obviously, put it back.)

Comment: When I used the script above, now I have another problem. I can't use variables inside replace formula.

sh '''ssh user@hostname "sed -E -i.bak 's%(user/service:).*%\1$version%' docker-compose.yml"'''

Will produce weird replacement text like this "/^A"

Comment: Try doubling the backslash; apparently something interprets `\1` as a character-code escape. If you need to interpolate variables inside the string, use triple double quotes instead of triple single quotes around the command; though this will again require more escaping of backslashes. This reinforces the recommendation to provide a [mre] with your *actual* requirements.